Adding cart item key in WooCommerce Cart HTML table doesn't show up
My WooCommerce Woo Cart Table element does not show cart_item_key value on each row, which I need to AJAX update my cart.
I tried creating a custom cart.php in a child theme, but that file is not being used.
How can I override the Woo Cart Table element to make sure that attribute is added?
my existing cart.php (and the one in my child theme) looks like below, but again, it does not add the data-cart-item-key value to the tr, so I believe the logic resides in "Woo Cart Table". But I can't find any logic when searching in folder wp_content for "Woo Cart Table" or "Woo_Cart_Table".
For what it's worth, I use the Avada theme.
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    error_log('test');
    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    $product_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>" data-cart-item-key="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>">


Maybe because you are using the new Cart Block instead of classic legacy Cart (shortcode). The new Cart Block doesn't use overridable templates like classic Cart and mostly doesn't accept customizations. Here is the way to switch back to classic Cart in WooCommerce
